# SQL Query in Marketing Cloud Today = date

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sql

I'm trying to query using a where clause such as this:  WHERE Today = a specific date .

This is what I have right now:
`DateAdd(day, 0, GetDate()) = '2018-02-12'` (because it was 2/12 when I posted/tested this)

Help!

Comment: Could you please try WHERE cast(GetDate() As Date) = '2018-02-12' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [CAST function](https://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-cast.html) in SQL converts data from one data type to another. By casting the GetDate() you're converting it to a string and comparing with a string in format of `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

You can do something like this:

```
WHERE cast(GetDate() As Date) = '2018-02-12'
```